# How to update database items using multiple threads within a transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, transactions, transactionscope

I hope you can help me

I'm writing an ASP.NET application and I have to loop on over more than 70,000 datarows within a datatable in order to update database records (each datatable row has information to update a database record).
My idea was to break the table into 10,000 rows tables and create some async methods to update the database (one async method per table).
I need to make sure every record on the table is updates, so everything is wrapped into a TransacionScope block.

The problem is, when I run the Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks() I get a Timeout exception telling me that the max allowed time to get a connection was finished.

My code is as follows

```
 using (TransactionScope transaccion = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TimeSpan(0, 120, 0)))
 {
 //Validando momentos                                        
 clConsultoraCompensationPlan.asignaValoresFinales(dtConsultoraCompensationPlan,
 compensation_plan, usuario,pagina);
 transaccion.Complete();
 }

private static void asignaValoresFinales(DataTable dtConsultorasMaster, clCompensationPlan compensation_plan, int usuario,Page pagina)
 {
 List<DataTable> lista_tablas = new List<DataTable>();
 //Separadno la tabla en 30 tablas
 foreach(IEnumerable<DataRow> renglones in LinqExtensions.Split(dtConsultorasMaster.AsEnumerable(), 50))
 {
 lista_tablas.Add(renglones.CopyToDataTable());
 }

 foreach (DataTable dtConsultoraCompensationPlan in lista_tablas)
 {
 AsignaValoresFinalesAsincrono tarea = new AsignaValoresFinalesAsincrono();
 PageAsyncTask tarea_asincrona = new PageAsyncTask(tarea.OnBegin, tarea.OnEnd, tarea.OnTimeout, new ContenedorAsignaValoresFinalesAsincrono(dtConsultoraCompensationPlan,compensation_plan,usuario), true);
 pagina.RegisterAsyncTask(tarea_asincrona);                
 }
 pagina.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
}
```

In order to run the query I'm using a singleton instance, does this affect something?
Is there a better way to complete this task rather than split the table and multithread?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timeout issue in your updates. If the transaction scope is using one connection then you probably need to update the command timeout in either the command or connection string.

Comment: The Transaction TimeOut is set to 2 hours

Should I add 
Connection Timeout=60
on the connection string?

Should I add it also on the command?

Comment: The Connection Timeout property instructs the connection how long it should poll for an active db connection. The command timeout is different because it dictates how long to wait for the sql command to complete.